# Regarding pipeline return value feature: error as Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'value'. Expected type is 'object'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

set_list is of child pipeline and sam_k is from main pipeline in "@concat(variables('set_list'),variables('sam_k'))" but i am getting error as Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'value'. Expected type is 'object'.

sam_k output:
{
"name": "sam_k",
"value": [
5,
1,
3
]
}

set_list output:
{
"name": "set_list",
"value": [
4,
2
]
}
expected:
{
"name": "sam_k",
"value": [
5,
1,
3,
4,
2
]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`concat` function in Azure Data Factory expects both arguments to be strings, not arrays. That's why you are getting the error message "Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'value'. Expected type is 'object'."

To concatenate two arrays in Azure Data Factory, you can use the union function instead.  The correct expression will look like,

`@union(variables('set_list'), variables('sam_k'))`

When the above expression is given, the data is concatenated as expected.
[image].

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that there might be a mismatch between the data types or structures of the inputs.

from the outputs you provided, it seems that both are themselves objects with name and value fields.

To concatenate the arrays correctly, you need to access the value arrays from both objects. Here's how you can adjust your expression:

```
"@concat(variables('set_list').value, variables('sam_k').value)"
```